# How to remove 0's converting pandas dataframe to record

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for an efficient way to remove zeros from a list of dictionaries created from a `pd.DataFrame` Take the following example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [0, 4]], columns=['a', 'b'], index=['x', 'y'])
df.to_dict('records')

[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 0, 'b': 4}]
```

What I would like is:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 4}]
```

I have a very large sparse dataframe, storing all of the zeros is inefficient. Because the dataframe is large I am looking for a faster solution than looping through the data frame of dictionaries and removing zeros, for instance the following works but is very slow and uses large amounts of memory.

```
new_records = []
for record in df.to_dict('records'):
    new_records.append(dict((k, v) for k, v in record.items() if v))
```

Is there a more efficient method or approach to this?

Comment: Have you considered just using sparse-matrices?

Comment: I am less familiar with sparse representations, though I believe you are correct that this would be a better way to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

use a list comprehension

```
[r[r != 0].to_dict() for _, r in df.iterrows()]

[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 4}]
```

Comment: This won't be faster, really, than the for-loop, at least not significantly so.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga `True`... still thinking

Answer (score 2):

This seems like an x-y problem: just use a sparse-matrix representation. The only difficulty is that you will have to keep track of columns yourself:

```
In [8]: from scipy import sparse

In [9]: df
Out[9]:
   a  b
x  1  2
y  0  4

In [10]: column_names = df.columns

In [11]: sm = sparse.csc_matrix(df.values)
```

Or, even easier, as pointed out by piRSquared, `pandas` built-in this functionality:

```
df.to_sparse(0)
```

Comment: I'm with you on this.  However, pandas has its own sparse  `df.to_sparse(0)`

Comment: @piRSquared Welp, even better!

Comment: I tried this, it doesn't seem to remove the 0 value for me.  Am I doing something wrong? df.to_sparse(0).to_dict('records')

Comment: @Kelvin if you use `to_dict` it will, of course, bring back the zeros. You need to use the sparse representation directly.

Comment: The issue I'm running into here is that converting the dataframe to a sparse representation is really, really slow. Much slower than converting the dataframe to a dictionary without zeros using a for loop or similar method. Is this expected?

Comment: @johnchase what data types are you dealing with? Are you using the `pandas.DataFrame.to_sparse` method or are you using `scipy.sparse`?

Comment: I am doing `df.to_sparse()` So using `pandas` rather than `scipy`

Comment: @johnchase use `scipy`. a `pandas` sparse dataframe is more heavy-weight and involved than a sparse representation form `scipy`

Answer (score 1):

```
> df.apply(lambda row: row[row != 0].to_dict(), 1)
x    {'b': 2, 'a': 1}
y            {'b': 4}
dtype: object
```

Comment: This won't be faster than the for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you decide to skip the sparse idea (good idea) and you really want a list of dictionaries like the one generated from a `pd.Dataframe` but lacking zeros, you could give a try to a solution using `numpy.flatnonzero()` and numpy indexes. I did some quick testing and it looks quicker than your proposed version, but no idea if the difference is significant.

```
import numpy as np

new_records = []
columns=np.array(df.columns.values)
for record in df.as_matrix():
    idx=np.flatnonzero(record)
    new_records.append( dict( zip( columns[idx], record[idx] ) ) )
```

The output is the one that you asked for:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'b': 4}]
```

#### Details:

- First retrieve the column values to use as keys for each new dictionary and make them a numpy array to use the numpy array index `np.array(df.columns.values)`.
- Next, convert the dataframe to a numpy matrix `df.as_matrix()`.
- For each record, get the index for positions without zero `np.flatnonzero()`
- Make a dictionary using the sliced version of the columns and records. Here is where the index is used `dict( zip( columns[idx], record[idx] ) )`
- Append each new dictionary to `new_records`